# How do I list all columns for a specified table that begin with a specific string

Tags: postgresql, information-schema, catalogs

How to select all the columns whose names begins with "img" from a PostgreSQL table?

I wrote that, but doesn't work

```
select 'img%' from mytable
```

Comment: Column's name begins with `img` or the content of this columns begins with `img`?

Comment: Hi, the name of the columns needs to begin with img (I don't mind the content). I have many columns named img1, img2, img3... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) views for this purpose:

```
create table tbl 
(
    id serial,
    img1 text,
    img2 text,
    foo int,
    bar int,
    img14 text
);
```

```
select table_catalog, table_name, column_name
from   information_schema.columns
where  table_catalog = 'postgres'
and    table_name = 'tbl'
and    column_name like 'img%';
```

> ```
> table_catalog | table_name | column_name
> :------------ | :--------- | :----------
> postgres      | tbl        | img1       
> postgres      | tbl        | img2       
> postgres      | tbl        | img14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=54b31553e79464531de0313e517b91bc)*

Comment: I supposed it was easier. The result I expected was keeping only the columns named img1, img2, img3 (until img227) from my table, dropping all the others.  Something like select img1, img2, img3, ..., img227 from mytable. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: You could build a dynamic query using the returned column's name.

Comment: It's the third day I'm into PostgreSQL. It's too much for me right now. Thank you very much